# WebClientProtocol.Timeout not Timing Out

Tags: c#, webservice-client

I'm calling a Web Service via SOAP. When the web service is down, we'd like it to fail rather quickly rather than wait the default timeout. I use the Timeout property for this:

```
service.Timeout = 5000;
```

which I think should time-out the operation after 5 seconds. However, I see that the operation doesn't time out until after 23 seconds, the same amount of time as the default timeout (ie, the above line not present).

I see that the exception thrown is "The operation has timed out", I just can't understand why it is not timing out in the time I've specified. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

Here's the test program:

```
long start = Environment.TickCount;
try {
  mdDqwsStatus.Service service = new mdDqwsStatus.Service();
  service.Timeout = 5000;                                        // 5 sec
  string response = service.GetServiceStatus(customerID, pafID); // This calls the WS
  long end1 = Environment.TickCount - start;                     // I never hit this line
} catch (Exception ex) {
  long end2 = Environment.TickCount - start;                     // Failure goes to here
  OutputError(Ex);
}
```

I set a breakpoint on the OutputError line and look at end2, and see 23000+ milliseconds.

Note that in the field, if the Web Service (which runs on IIS) has been stopped, the delay is quite short. However, if the machine is down or there's connectivity issues, the delay is 23 seconds (or sometimes even quite longer).

Comment: You're setting it before calling a service method?

Comment: The default timeout period is 100 seconds so something is in fact happening, just not when you expect it to. I would speculate the exception isn't being thrown when you expect it to because you don't fully understand the state transitions of the program http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789041.aspx

Comment: Is it 23 seconds til the channel faults or closes? Or 23 seconds until you get the exception?

Comment: I've added some code to better describe the problem.

Comment: 23 seconds would a very odd default timeout value.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, it sure is, especially when I requested only 5.